# Swift NSDictionary Child types

Tags: ios, swift

I'm having a lot of frustration with Swift when it comes to working with Dictionaries and NSDictionaries.

I am pulling data from a server. One of the values is a Bool.

I started with a Swift Dictionary and moved to NSDictionary out of frustration. However, I still cannot get the values from the dictionary.

All of the following fail with contradictory errors:

```
let  unread:Bool = data!["unread"] as! Bool
let  unread:Bool = data?["unread"] as! Bool
let  unread:Bool = data?.objectForKey("unread") as! Bool
let  unread:NSNumber = data?["unread"] as! NSNumber
```

error: Could not cast value of type 'NSTaggedPointerString' (0x110c1eae8) to 'NSNumber' (0x10e0ab2a0).

Okay, looks like that data is coming in as a String... let's try:

```
let unreadStr:String = data!["unread"] as! String
let unreadStr:NSString = data!["unread"] as! NSString
```

error: Could not cast value of type '__NSCFBoolean' (0x1097413b8) to 'NSString' (0x106bcdb48).

So I'm confused. When I try to convert it to a Bool it says I cannot convert a String to a Number. When I try to convert it to a String, it says I cannot convert a number to a string.

Here is what the data looks like:

```
Optional({
    senderId = 10154040;
    sent = 1460844986973;
    text = "Test Message 1";
    unread = false;
})
```

Comment: This is how I transform the data from the server:                                            if let dict:NSDictionary =  snapShot.value as? NSDictionary{
                let data = dict.allValues[0] as? NSDictionary

Comment: Could it be that your server is sending you inconsistent representations of Bool — sometimes as a String, other times as a Bool?

Comment: I just hooked up SwiftyJSON and everything works great now. https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

Comment: How exactly are you pulling these values from your server? Is it JSON?

Answer (score 2):

You should try something along these lines:

```
let data: [String : Any] = ["first" : "test", "second" : 2, "third" : true]

let first = data["first"] as! String
let second = data["second"] as! Int
let third = data["third"] as! Bool

print(first)
print(second)
print(third)
```